# Is there a system variable for opening directory files?

Tags: automationanywhere

Please is there a system variable for opening a directory on automation
anywhere?
I don't want to use keystrokes.

Comment: The technology is Automation Anywhere for Enterprise.

Comment: Please be more precise. What do you mean? A `variable` cannot open a directory. You need an action. And what do you mean by "opening" a directory? Opening a windows explorer folder? And if so, what possible purpose could this have?

Answer (score 0):

There are inbuilt System variable for Directories for Automation Anywhere Files. However If you want to have your own variable for particular directory/folder you can define that variable and give it's initial value of directory that you are interested in.and use this variable where ever you want to perform various commands operation related to Files/Folder operations.